# how to create a setup application on MacOS X?

Tags: macos, installation

I have HTML website which I need to distribute as standalone app. For Windows, I use Chrome Portable + Inno Setup - and everything is simple and straightforward. Client requested, however, to be able to install this app on MAC computers. I have no experience with Mac, so I have few questions here:

1. Is DMG the only way to install programs on MAC?
2. Are there any tool (similar to Inno Setup) which will be able to "wrap" chrome portable and my HTML code into setup program?
3. How to "sign" the final DMG (I have code signing certificate I'm using on Windows, I assume something similar exists on MAC).

Thank you, and I appreciate your help.